Using #line 0 directive in MSVC: Valid but flagged by IntelliSense?
I’m working on a project where I preprocess code and add some definitions at the beginning. To maintain accurate line numbers for error reporting, I’m using the #line directive. According to the Microsoft documentation, #line 0 is valid, and it compiles correctly with MSVC. However, IntelliSense in Visual Studio flags it as an error with the message ‘invalid line number.’
From Microsoft

The digit-sequence value can be any integer constant within the range from 0 to 2147483647, inclusive. Macro replacement can be used on the preprocessing tokens, but the result must evaluate to the correct syntax.

Project compiles perfectly with no error report or warning from compiler, And it also reports the correct line numbers, Only thing that concerns me is the error from IntelliSense :

Severity Code Description : Error (active) E0034 invalid line number

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is using #line 0 safe and reliable in MSVC, or should I avoid it due to potential undefined behavior? Any insights or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Why you are using this directive at all? This suppose to be used by preprocessor only, when preprocessor resolves all #includes and which keep line numbers consistent with original source files.

@MarekR Because I am working also on a preprocessor, Making an IDE.

Intellisense uses the clang compiler... so maybe that's where the error comes from

@PepijnKramer Are you sure? I've looked for it and it seems only Visual Code uses clang for Intellisense.

Yes it uses clang (I just verified), create the following source file : int main() {  __popcnt(42); } this will happily compile with MSVC. But if you look at the intellisense (red squiggles) message (mouse over) it says : "Identifier "__popcnt" is undefined. clang-diagnostics-unused-value: ignoring return value of function declared with const attribute".

The C++ standard has this to say: "[cpp.line]/3 If the digit sequence specifies zero or a number greater than 2147483647, the behavior is undefined." Accepting #line 0 as valid seems to be a compiler-specific, non-portable extension.

@PepijnKramer AFAIK, IntelliSense uses Edison Design Group (EDG) C++ frontend since VS2010. This is not Clang.

@PepijnKramer I think you are using clang-llvm build chain? I did __popcnt(42); and there is no error from Intellisense

No I was not, I am starting to think it is dependent on the actual version of visual studio... latest I read is that IntelliSense even started using copilot stuff. I think the one thing I can take away from this is, intellisense is not using the msvc compiler itself.  Actual documentation is hard to find.
